# Is Objective-C necessary for iOS development?

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What programming languages can one use to develop iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad (iOs) applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949995/what-programming-languages-can-one-use-to-develop-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad-i)

I have a load of fairly simple scientific programs that I converted from Basic to C.  I would like to put them onto the Apple App Store, and was just wondering if it is necessary to convert them to Obj-C first, or will the C code be OK as a start?
They are simple 'get user input', 'do some logic checks', 'do the calcs', 'output result' type progs.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can read more about in this topic in the [following SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3950027/703919). I hope it helps.!

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C has a fully functioning C underneath, and you can write pure C code and have it working.

However, i doubt you would be able to release a command-line application to App Store. You would have to create a user interface in Xcode, and that would definitely introduce Objective-C to your program. With that said, as long as you connect your program variables (outlets) to controls on the UI, and link UI buttons back to the program's functions (actions/methods), the main processing body of your function could be a copy of your C code.

Comment: I concur you can maintain your logic in C, but build the UI using IOS outlets and you're golden.  Nevertheless, if you are a proficient C programmer you might want to give Objective C a try, you might like it.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that I would need to develop all the UI stuff  in XCode, and that's OK. I just wondered if the basic C code will work OK.

Comment: @user1854150, if this answer satisfies your question, please consider "accepting" the answer